# Count rows based on multiple consecutive time flows

Tags: r, time

I have a large file of time-series data, which looks as follows. The dataset covers years, in increments of 15 minutes. A small subset looks like:

```
uniqueid     time
a            2014-04-30 23:30:00 
a            2014-04-30 23:45:00
a            2014-05-01 00:00:00
a            2014-05-01 00:15:00
a            2014-05-12 13:45:00
a            2014-05-12 14:00:00
b            2014-05-12 13:45:00
b            2014-05-12 14:00:00
b            2014-05-12 14:30:00
```

To reproduce above:

```
time<-c("2014-04-30 23:30:00","2014-04-30 23:45:00","2014-05-01 00:00:00","2014-05-01 00:15:00",
    "2014-05-12 13:45:00","2014-05-12 14:00:00","2014-05-12 13:45:00","2014-05-12 14:00:00",
    "2014-05-12 14:30:00")

uniqueid<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b")
mydf<-data.frame(uniqueid,time)
```

My goal is to count the number of rows per unique id, per consecutive timeflow. A consecutive timespan is when a unique id is stamped for each 15 minutes in a row (such as id A, which is stamped from 30.04.14 23.30 hrs until 01.05.14 00.15 hrs - hence 4 rows), yet when this flow of 15-minute iterations is disrupted (after 01.05.14 00:15, it is not stamped at 01.05.14 00:30 hence it is disrupted), it should count the next timestamp as start of a new consecutive timeflow and again calculate the number of rows until this flow is disrupted again. Time is POSIX.

As you can see in above example; a consecutive timeflow may cover different days, different months, or different years. I have many unique ids (and as said, a very large file), so I'm looking for a way that my computer can handle (loops probably wouldn't work).

I am looking for output something like:

```
uniqueid    flow     number_rows
a           1        4
a           2        2
b           3        2
b           4        1
```

I have looked into some time packages (such as lubridate), but given my limited R knowledge, I don't even know where to begin.

I hope all is clear - if not, I'd be happy to try to clarify it further. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this with `data.table` also using a time difference would be to make use of the `data.table` internal values for group number and number of rows in each group:

```
library(data.table)
res<-setDT(mydf)[, list(number_rows=.N,flow=.GRP),
                 by=.(uniqueid,cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(time,shift(time,1L,type="lag",fill=0))) - 15))][,cumsum:=NULL]
print(res)

   uniqueid number_rows flow
1:        a           4    1
2:        a           2    2
3:        b           2    3
4:        b           1    4
```

Also since the sample data you posted didn't align with the subset you posted, I have included my data below:

**Data**

```
time<-as.POSIXct(c("2014-04-30 23:30:00","2014-04-30 23:45:00","2014-05-01 00:00:00","2014-05-01 00:15:00",
        "2014-05-12 13:45:00","2014-05-12 14:00:00","2014-05-12 13:45:00","2014-05-12 14:00:00",
        "2014-05-12 14:30:00"))


uniqueid<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b")
mydf<-data.frame(uniqueid,time)
```

Comment: Nice! If you `unclass(mydf$time)` and check for difference to be `15*60 = 900L`, it'd be tad faster.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Works perfect and fast. And apologies for the wrong sample data, have adjusted it in the post now.

Comment: And thanks Arun for the comment concerning speed, will include this to make it run faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby the `uniqueid` and the cumulative sum of the difference of time between rows which is not equal to `15 min` and that gives the flow `id` and then a count of rows should give you what you need:

A justification of the logic is whenever the time difference is not equal to `15` within each `uniqueid`, a new flow process should be generated so we label it as `TRUE` and combine that with the `cumsum`, it becomes a new `flow` id with the following consecutive rows:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf$time <- as.POSIXct(mydf$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# convert the time column to POSIXct class so that we can apply the diff function correctly
mydf %>% group_by(uniqueid, flow = 1 + cumsum(c(F, diff(time) != 15))) %>% 
         summarize(num_rows = n())

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: uniqueid [?]
# 
#   uniqueid  flow num_rows
#     <fctr> <dbl>    <int>
# 1        a     1        4
# 2        a     2        2
# 3        b     3        2
# 4        b     4        1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Yet indeed as ARobertson notes, dplyr is too slow with a dataset this large. Further, the solution works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Base R is pretty fast. Using crude benchmarking, I found it finished in half the time of DT, and I got tired of waiting for dplyr.

```
# estimated size of data, years x days x hours x 15mins x uniqueids
5*365*24*4*1000 # = approx 180M

# make data with posixct and characters of 180M rows, mydf is approx 2.5GB in memory
time<-rep(as.POSIXct(c("2014-04-30 23:30:00","2014-04-30 23:45:00","2014-05-01 00:00:00","2014-05-01 00:15:00",
        "2014-05-12 13:45:00","2014-05-12 14:00:00","2014-05-12 13:45:00","2014-05-12 14:00:00",
        "2014-05-12 14:30:00")),times = 20000000)

uniqueid<-rep(as.character(c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b")),times = 20000000)

mydf<-data.frame(uniqueid,time = time)
rm(time,uniqueid);gc()
```

Base R:

```
# assumes that uniqueid's are in groups and in order, and there won't be a followed by b that have the 15 minute "flow"
starttime <- Sys.time()

# find failed flows
mydf$diff <- c(0,diff(mydf$time))
mydf$flowstop <- mydf$diff != 15

# give each flow an id
mydf$flowid <- cumsum(mydf$flowstop)

# clean up vars
mydf$time <- mydf$diff <- mydf$flowstop <- NULL

# find flow length
mydfrle <- rle(mydf$flowid)

# get uniqueid/flowid pairs (unique() is too slow)
mydf <- mydf[!duplicated(mydf$flowid), ]

# append rle and remove separate var
mydf$number_rows <- mydfrle$lengths
rm(mydfrle)

print(Sys.time()-starttime)
# Time difference of 30.39437 secs
```

data.table:

```
library(data.table)
starttime <- Sys.time()
res<-setDT(mydf)[, list(number_rows=.N,flow=.GRP),
                 by=.(uniqueid,cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(time,shift(time,1L,type="lag",fill=0))) - 15))][,cumsum:=NULL]
print(Sys.time()-starttime)
# Time difference of 57.08156 secs
```

dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
# convert the time column to POSIXct class so that we can apply the diff function correctly
starttime <- Sys.time()
mydf %>% group_by(uniqueid, flow = 1 + cumsum(c(F, diff(time) != 15))) %>% 
  summarize(num_rows = n())
print(Sys.time()-starttime)
# too long, did not finish after a few minutes
```

I think the assumption of uniqueid's and times being in order is huge, and the other solutions might be able to take advantage of that better. order() is easy enough to do.

I'm not sure about the impact of memory, or of the impact of different data sets that aren't so simple. It should be easy enough to break it into chunks and process if memory is an issue. It takes more code in Base R for sure.

Comment: This is not really correct. Do `mydf$time[6] = as.POSIXct("2014-05-12 13:30:00")` on data provided by MikeyMike and try again...

Comment: As Arun notes, this solution does not take the difference in uniqueids into account when the increment between them is still 15..

Comment: That assumption was stated in the first line of the Base R code chunk (on second look, it's a poorly placed comment for its importance). It's a reasonable assumption if all time periods end at the time the data was pulled or recording stopped. The speed increase was significant enough to post because I usually find DT and dplyr much faster regardless. If the data needs to be broken up anyway because of size or other issues, it's easy enough to break into chunks by ID to avoid that problem, and then parallel processing is an option for more speed. It's not generally correct, but it might work.

Answer (score 2):

Having both ordered "id" and "time" columns, we could build a single group to operate on by creating a logical vector of indices wherever either "id" changes or "time" is > 15 minutes.

With:

```
id = as.character(mydf$uniqueid)
tm = mydf$time
```

find where "id":

```
id_gr = c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-length(id)])
```

and "time":

```
tm_gr = c(0, difftime(tm[-1], tm[-length(tm)], unit = "mins")) > 15
```

change and combine them in:

```
gr = id_gr | tm_gr
```

which shows wherever either "id" changed or "time" > 15.
And to get the result:

```
tab = tabulate(cumsum(gr))  ## basically, the only operation per group -- 'n by group'
data.frame(id = id[gr], flow = seq_along(tab), n = tab)
#  id flow n
#1  a    1 4
#2  a    2 2
#3  b    3 2
#4  b    4 1
```

On a larger scale:

```
set.seed(1821); nid = 1e4         
dat = replicate(nid, as.POSIXct("2016-07-07 12:00:00 EEST") + 
                     cumsum(sample(c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 150, 200, 250, 300), sample(5e2:1e3, 1), TRUE)*60),
                simplify = FALSE)
names(dat) = make.unique(rep_len(letters, nid))
dat = data.frame(id = rep(names(dat), lengths(dat)), time = do.call(c, dat))

system.time({
    id = as.character(dat$id); tm = dat$time
    id_gr = c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-length(id)])
    tm_gr = c(0, difftime(tm[-1], tm[-length(tm)], unit = "mins")) > 15
    gr = id_gr | tm_gr
    tab = tabulate(cumsum(gr))
    ans1 = data.frame(id = id[gr], flow = seq_along(tab), n = tab)
})
# user  system elapsed 
#  1.44    0.19    1.66
```

For comparison, included MikeyMike's answer:

```
library(data.table)
dat2 = copy(dat)
system.time({
    ans2 = setDT(dat2)[, list(flow = .GRP, n = .N),
                by = .(id, cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(time, 
                                      shift(time, 1L, type = "lag", fill = 0), 
      unit = "mins")) > 15))][, cumsum := NULL]    
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.95    0.22    4.26

identical(as.data.table(ans1), ans2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This worked absolutely amazing. Fastest so far and very straight-forward. Thank you very much!!

Comment: An additional question; I want to perform some calculations based on the original df (there are more columns in the df that I didn't include in the example). How would you go about translating the flow number back to the original dataset (so each row gets its flownr assigned, hence multiple rows would have the same flownr)?

Comment: @zoekdestep : If I understand it right, you need something like, say, `cbind(mydf, flow = cumsum(gr))`? I.e. having `gr` and applying `cumsum` gives a `nrow(mydf)` vector.

Comment: as simple as that :) thank you so, so much, you really helped me!!